# Microphone recognised in pavucontrol but not useable

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone

I'm running Pop OS on a Lenovo T495s. My onboard microphone was working fine but after updating to 20.04 I am getting no sound from it.

When I run pavucontrol I see two input devices:

- Digital Microphone - Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Audio Controller Digital Microphone. Shows no input.
- Headphones Stereo Microphone (unplugged) - Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Headphones Stereo Microphone. This *does* show input.

I'm not quite sure what the first devices is and it seems like I want to use the bottom one but only "Digital Microphone" is available to select in the OS Sound settings, or when using a microphone in a browser.

Why is the second microphone not available to use?

Comment: I have the same problem on my HP Probook 455 G7 with Kubuntu 20.04. I cannot set the "Headphones Stereo Microphone" as default for my system. But I can choose to use it as sound input from individual programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 20.04. What I did was to update the linux kernel. If you type

uname -a

to find out which version you have, then see if you are on 5.6 or 5.8

I was on 5.6-1020 and then updated to 5.8 by using the following command:

sudo apt install linux-image-5.8.0-23-generic  linux-headers-5.8.0-23-generic linux-buildinfo-5.8.0-23-generic linux-modules-5.8.0-23-generic linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-23-generic

I noticed that in PulseAudio Volume Control, I can now actually disable the non working microphone under the configuration tab. Whereas before I couldn't.

Comment: That sort of worked. I am now able to see "Internal Microphone" in the Sound Settings dialog and it appears to be getting some input. However the only input I am able to select in a browser is the output monitor.

Comment: Oh wait! Now it works. Not sure what else I did but that seems to have done it. Thanks!

Comment: 5.8 doesn't seem sufficient for me, I see the headphones microphone as being unplugged in puvacontrol... and yet it detects some sound.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on HP Probook 455 G7 with Kubuntu 20.04. Updating to the upstream kernel 5.9.1 solved this issue for me https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#How_do_I_install_an_upstream_kernel.3F